# Is my crash log only partly symbolicated, and why? What does EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, debug-symbols

Apple rejected my app (OS Version 7.1.2 on iPhone 5S) and send the crash log. The crash never occured on my testing devices nor in the simulator, so I am stuck with the crash log. I understand, I have to symbolicate the crash log.

This is my first app, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

I go to the Organizer (Xcode 5.1.1), import the .crash file from Apple, and what I get is the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18441f100 0x184314000 + 1093888
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x190dfc1fc 0x190df4000 + 33276
2   CoreFoundation                  0x184320918 0x184314000 + 51480
3   MedSafe                         0x1000596dc -[MRPatientenViewController done:] (MRPatientenViewController.m:396)
4   UIKit                           0x18741d0b0 0x1873d4000 + 299184
5   UIKit                           0x18741d0b0 0x1873d4000 + 299184
6   UIKit                           0x18741d044 0x1873d4000 + 299076
7   UIKit                           0x187406520 0x1873d4000 + 206112
8   UIKit                           0x18741ca44 0x1873d4000 + 297540
9   UIKit                           0x18741c6d8 0x1873d4000 + 296664
10  UIKit                           0x187417370 0x1873d4000 + 275312
11  UIKit                           0x1873e8b50 0x1873d4000 + 84816
12  UIKit                           0x1873e6c40 0x1873d4000 + 76864
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1843df7f4 0x184314000 + 833524
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1843deb50 0x184314000 + 830288
15  CoreFoundation                  0x1843dcde8 0x184314000 + 822760
16  CoreFoundation                  0x18431ddd0 0x184314000 + 40400
17  GraphicsServices                0x189fbdc0c 0x189fb0000 + 56332
18  UIKit                           0x18744efc4 0x1873d4000 + 503748
19  MedSafe                         0x10008bdf4 main (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x1913efaa0 0x1913ec000 + 15008


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914ea58c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019147e804 abort + 108
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001906a4990 abort_message + 84
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001906c1c28 default_terminate_handler() + 296
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190dfc4d0 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001906bf164 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001906bed38 __cxa_rethrow + 140
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190dfc3a4 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018431de48 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
9   GraphicsServices                0x0000000189fbdc08 GSEventRunModal + 164
10  UIKit                           0x000000018744efc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
11  MedSafe                         0x000000010008bdf0 main (main.m:16)
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001913efa9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914d1aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001913d5998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914eae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191569548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914eae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191569548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914d1ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843ded20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843dceb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018431ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184373454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   CoreMotion                      0x0000000184ad6538 0x184a98000 + 255288
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019156be18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019156bd70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191569550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001914eae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191569548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fdd34d8
x4: 0x0000000000002060   x5: 0x000000016fdd3590   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000640
x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000943376f7  x11: 0x0000000000000300
x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000191497dcb
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000c5cd8043e48b  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x000000019434a2a0  x21: 0x434c4e47432b2b00  x22: 0x434c4e47432b2b00  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000178151b40  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000178002e00  x27: 0x00000001917fd410
x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fdd3510   lr: 0x000000019156d16c
sp: 0x000000016fdd34f0   pc: 0x00000001914ea58c cpsr: 0x00000000


Binary images....
```

I guess, this means, the app crashes in MRPatientenViewController.m line 396.
But why there is not more stack trace? Am I doing the symbolication not correctly?

BTW, here is the method which crashes:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
if (debug==1) {
    NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(MRMedSafeAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

if ([self.callingSegue isEqualToString:@"add_patient"] || [self.callingSegue isEqualToString:@"add_patient_from_home"]) {

    if ([self.vornameTextField.text isEqualToString:@("")]) {
        // kein Vorname, zeige Alert, dass Vorname eingegeben werden muss, und abbrechen
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vorname fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Vorname eingeben."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    if ([self.nachnameTextField.text isEqualToString:@("")]) {
        // kein Nachname, zeige Alert, dass Vorname eingegeben werden muss, und abbrechen
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nachname fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Nachname eingeben."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    if ([_dateTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        // kein Geburtsdatum, zeige Alert, dass Geburtsdatum eingegeben werden muss, und abbrechen
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Geburtdatum fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Geburtsdatum eingeben."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailTextField.text] == NO && (![self.emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inkorrekte Email-Addresse!"
                                                        message:@"Bitte geben Sie eine korrekte oder keine Email-Addresse ein."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    if ([_krankenkassenTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Krankenkasse fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Krankenkasse wählen."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }

    // check if we can create a local reminder calender for medicaments
    if(![self createLocalCalendarForMedicamentReminders]){
        // No calendar created
        NSLog(@"No Calendar created.");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Kein Kalendar erstellt!"
                                                        message:@"Es konnte kein Kalendar für Medikament-Erinnerungen erstellt werden. Bitte aktivieren Sie -> Einstellungen -> iCloud -> Erinnerungen."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    // check if we can create a local reminder calender for impfungen
    if(![self createLocalCalendarForImpfungReminders]){
        // No calendar created
        NSLog(@"No Calendar created.");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Kein Kalendar erstellt!"
                                                        message:@"Es konnte kein Kalendar für Impfung-Erinnerungen erstellt werden. Bitte aktivieren Sie -> Einstellungen -> iCloud -> Erinnerungen."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    Patient *patient = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Patient" inManagedObjectContext:[cdh context]];
    patient.vorname = self.vornameTextField.text;
    patient.nachname = self.nachnameTextField.text;

    patient.reminder_calendar_id = _medikamentCalendarId;
    patient.reminder_calendar_title = _medikamentCalendarTitle;

    patient.reminder_impfungen_calendar_id = _impfungCalendarId;
    patient.reminder_impfungen_calendar_title = _impfungCalendarTitle;
    patient.email = self.emailTextField.text;
    patient.geburtsdatum = _datePicker.date;
    patient.erinnern_med_verbraucht = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    patient.erinnern_med_tage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:7];
    patient.erinnern_med_minute = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    patient.erinnern_med_stunde = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
    patient.versichertennummer = _versichertenNummerTextField.text;


    if (self.genderSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        patient.weiblich = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    } else {
        patient.weiblich = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    patient.krankenkasse = [self.krankenkassenArray objectAtIndex:[_krankenkassenPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    // because this is a new profile, there is no need to delete the old file
    // save the new file under unique name which is in imageName
    patient.imagename = self.imageName;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    [self saveImage:self.userImageView.image byName:self.imageName inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
    [cdh saveContext];

    NSArray *einnahmeZeiten = [self fetchEinnahmeZeiten];
    for (EinnahmeZeit *einnahmeZeit in einnahmeZeiten) {
        NSLog(@"einnahmeZeit: %@", einnahmeZeit);
        PatientEinnahmeZeit *patientEinnahmeZeit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PatientEinnahmeZeit" inManagedObjectContext:[cdh context]];
        patientEinnahmeZeit.patient = patient;
        NSString *name = einnahmeZeit.name;
        patientEinnahmeZeit.name = name;
        int ordinal = [einnahmeZeit.ordinal intValue];
        int minute = [einnahmeZeit.minute intValue];
        int stunde = [einnahmeZeit.stunde intValue];
        patientEinnahmeZeit.ordinal = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ordinal];
        patientEinnahmeZeit.minute = [NSNumber numberWithInt:minute];
        patientEinnahmeZeit.stunde = [NSNumber numberWithInt:stunde];
        [cdh saveContext];
    }
    MRSingleton *singleton = [MRSingleton sharedMRSingleton];
    [singleton saveCurrentPatient:patient];
    //[cdh saveContext];

    MRHomeViewController *hvc = (MRHomeViewController *)self.delegate;
    hvc.patientJustAdded = YES;


    hvc.aufgabenArray = nil;
    [hvc.aufgabenTableView reloadData];
    [hvc fetchAufgabenInBackground];

    [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

} else if ([self.callingSegue isEqualToString:@"edit_patient"] || [self.callingSegue isEqualToString:@"edit_patient_from_acc"]) {

    if ([self.vornameTextField.text isEqualToString:@("")]) {
        // kein Vorname, zeige Alert, dass Vorname eingegeben werden muss, und abbrechen
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vorname fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Vorname eingeben."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    if ([self.nachnameTextField.text isEqualToString:@("")]) {
        // kein Nachname, zeige Alert, dass Vorname eingegeben werden muss, und abbrechen
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nachname fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Nachname eingeben."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    if ([_krankenkassenTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Krankenkasse fehlt!"
                                                          message:@"Bitte Krankenkasse wählen."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailTextField.text] == NO && (![self.emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inkorrekte Email-Addresse!"
                                                        message:@"Bitte geben Sie eine korrekte oder keine Email-Addresse ein."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }


    // check if there is already a patient with this nachname, vorname and geburtsdatum
    NSArray *patients = [self fetchPatientWithNachname:self.nachnameTextField.text andVorname:self.vornameTextField.text andGeburtsdatum:self.datePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"patients count: %d", [patients count]);
    if ([patients count] > 0) {
        Patient *duplicate = [patients objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"duplicate objectID: %@", [duplicate objectID]);
        NSLog(@"self.selectedObjectID: %@", self.selectedObjectID);
        if (![[duplicate objectID] isEqual:self.selectedObjectID]) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Patient existiert bereits!"
                                                            message:@"Es existiert bereits ein Patient mit diesem Nachnamen, Vornamen und Geburtsdatum."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
    }

    Patient *patient = (Patient *)[cdh.context existingObjectWithID:self.selectedObjectID error:nil];
    patient.vorname = self.vornameTextField.text;
    patient.nachname = self.nachnameTextField.text;
    patient.email = self.emailTextField.text;
    patient.geburtsdatum = _datePicker.date;

    patient.versichertennummer = _versichertenNummerTextField.text;

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];




    if (self.genderSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        patient.weiblich = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    } else {
        patient.weiblich = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    patient.krankenkasse = [self.krankenkassenArray objectAtIndex:[self.krankenkassenPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    // check if there if a new image was picked
    if (self.imageChanged) {
        // because this is an existing profile, we need to save the file and delete the old file
        NSString *oldFilename = patient.imagename;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // delete old file
        [self deleteImageByName:oldFilename inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
        // save the new file
        [self saveImage:self.userImageView.image byName:self.imageName inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
        patient.imagename = self.imageName;
    } else {
        //
    }

    [cdh saveContext];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Unknown calling segue");
}
}
```

Line 396 is:

`patient.krankenkasse = [self.krankenkassenArray objectAtIndex:[_krankenkassenPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];`

Any suggestions?

Comment: It can only symblicate the part of the stack that were in your code. At a guess i would say that patient, krankenkassenArray or the pickerview were nil or released. Try running with zombies enabled

Comment: I am guessing the same. But how can it be that this bug would only happen on some devices? There is only the main thread running, no concurrent execution, so how can this kind of error only occur on some devices?

Comment: It can be differences in the exact sequence they used or even different levels of optimisation between your debug build and the release build.

Comment: @Paulw11 Does that mean, that I correctly symbolicated the crash log?

Comment: I would say yes - it go you to the line that crashed